# Performing a Right Join?

Tags: mysql

```
Books
id | title

Articles
id | title | book_id
```

I need to get all articles that are from a particular book:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE book_id = 10
```

With this query I also need to get the parents book title.

I presume I need a right join for this:

```
SELECT books.title, articles.* FROM books 
RIGHT JOIN articles ON book.id = articles.book_id WHERE books.id = 10
```

Is this correct? Or is a right join not the way to go?

Comment: Your `outer join` is being negated by the `where` criteria.  If the `book_id` has to exist in the `books` table, then an `inner join` is probably better suited.

Comment: So an inner join is the way to go? Would it be quicker to do 2 x quires. One to get all of the articles and another just to get the book title?

Comment: No. That would be ridiculous.